# Route to page that is clicked from the dropdown list

Tags: python, html, flask

running the snippet you will see that that sign-up and sign-in both of them having 2 different registration/log-in. In the flask, can i write an if condition that if doctor registration is clicked to route to webpage of doc registration, and if the patient registration is clicked to route to patient registration page, or i should make 2 separate routes?

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
              </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Doctor Registration</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Patient Registration</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="docreg"><a href="#">Doctor Log In</a></li>
                        <li class="patreg"><a href="#">Patient Log In</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
@medAI.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

Comment: You don't have to make two different routes, but that seems like your best option. You do need two different URLs, although they could point to one route.

Comment: @AlexHall man any example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of Variable Rules in Flask to maintain a single route for registration.

```
@medAI.route('/register/<path:subpath>')
def register(subpath):
    if subpath=="doctor":
        return "Doctor Registration"
    elif subpath=="patient":
        return "Patient Registration"
    return "Invalid Registration Attempt"
```

For more information, you can refer to [this section](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) of the official documentation.

Comment: Any reason for `path:`?

Comment: @AlexHall TBH I don't have any particular reason to use `path` instead of `string`. The latter should work fine, I guess? Do let me know if I'm not aware of something important.

Comment: man i try to 127.0.0.1:5000/register/doctor or 127.0.0.1:5000/register/patient, but it gives me error 404?

Comment: @leocleo I tested it out and it works fine for me. Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: @AlexHall, man i used string instead of path and it worked smoothly.